# C++ Area of a Trapezoid calculator not working

Tags: visual-c++

So I've been learning basic cpp and I was making some calculators for some practice over some skills that I learned and I made about 5 of them just fine, but when I tried making this area of a trapezoid calculator it isn't working.

This is my code

```
std::cout << "Enter a Base " << std::endl;
int a;
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "Enter a Base" << std::endl;
int b;
std::cin >> b;
std::cout << "Enter a Height" << std::endl;
int c;
std::cin >> c;
std::cout << "Area = " << a + b * c / 2.0 << std::endl;

return 0;
```

I coded in the formula for the area correctly, but for example when I type in 6 and 5 for the bases and 1 for the height, it will enter 8.5 as the area instead of 5.5. Does anyone have any ideas to fix this, (i'm using windows visual studio) thanks.

Comment: The formula can't be right - it adds up meters and meters squared. Are you perhaps missing some parentheses?

Comment: am I able to use parenthesis in the std::cout << >>? will the compiler look at it as though its order of operations

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Anyway, what happens when you try?

Comment: Oh wow it works

Comment: thanks alot! this will come in handy